# What's so special about Prince Shotoku?

Tags: amagi-brilliant-park

Kanie said he did an impression of Prince Shotoku in episode 10. Mofu got really excited, and according to [Shotoku's Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Sh%C5%8Dtoku), he was some sort of big shot back in the old days.

I don't really get why Mofu would be so excited, why Kanie would think an impression of Shotoku is a good idea, or what someone would do to impersonate someone from over a 1000 years ago?

Comment: After watching that scene again, I'm not convinced this is anything more than a throwaway gag. I also don't see doing an impression of Shotoku as much more unusual than of any other historical figure (e.g. George Washington or Julius Caesar).